# Lossless crop n drop (cut and paste) for JPEGs

Tags: image-processing, jpeg

I'm looking for examples/blog posts/etc of lossless jpeg operations (crop n drop = cut and paste). I know there is a program `jpegtran` (http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran) which can perform lossless cropping (in certain situations), but there seems to be a lack of good documentation.   Yes, I have tried the google.

`jpegtran` also has an experimental branch that allows lossless dropping (= pasting) in certain situations, but the documentation of this seems to be even worse.

What about jpegtran's `drop` switch is experimental? Does it have known issues? Do people use it?

`drop` seems like a really cool and useful feature, and I find it odd that it's been experimental for over 10 years...

And yes, one could use lossless formats such as PNG for such operations, but I'm specifically interested in JPEGs.

Thanks!

Comment: Or are people aware of other alternatives for loss-less croping and pasting of JPEGs?

Comment: Generally cut or copy operations involve reading the file into memory in a standard format, making it automatically lossless from that point forward. Lossless cropping involves writing the cropped image back to a JPEG file. It has limitations on the size of the image and the boundaries of the crop.

Answer (score 19):

I spent entirely too much time trying to figure this out, so here's hoping this helps someone else. This question is pretty high on Google when searching for docs on this so-called "crop 'n drop" feature.

Overview:

`jpegtran -drop` allows you to "drop" the blocks from one JPEG onto another JPEG.

It only replaces existing blocks, it will not expand the input, so you cannot concatenate two JPEGs with only `-drop`.

However, if you supply a `-crop` parameter larger than the input image, JPEGTran will write out blank (grey) blocks to expand to the desired size. You can *then* use `-drop` to replace these new, blank blocks with your desired image.

Behold my crappy ASCII-art example:

1. You have two images, `A.jpg` and `B.jpg`, both have dimensions of `256x256`. We want to concatenate these side-by-side to produce a `512x256` image.

   ```
   +---------+  +---------+
   |         |  |         |
   |  A.jpg  |  |  B.jpg  |
   |         |  |         |
   +---------+  +---------+
   ```
2. "Uncrop" `A.jpg` to the size required. The `-crop` parameter is standard X11 geometry notation: WIDTHxHEIGHT+X+Y Positive X/Y values measure from the top/left, and negative values from the bottom/right, respectively.

   ```
   jpegtran -crop 512x256+0+0 -outfile O.jpg A.jpg

   +---------+---------+
   |         \         |
   |  O.jpg  \ (blank) |
   |         \         |
   +---------+---------+
   ```
3. Now "drop" `B.jpg` into the new, blank section in `O.jpg` The `-drop` parameter uses just the origin X/Y coordinates.

   ```
   jpegtran -drop +256+0 B.jpg -outfile O.jpg O.jpg

   +---------+---------+    +---------+
   |         \         |    |         |
   |  O.jpg  \    o<========|  B.jpg  |
   |         \         |    |         |
   +---------+---------+    +---------+
   ```
4. Done! You now have a single file, `O.jpg`, with dimensions of `512x256`, that contains the concatenated contents of `A.jpg` and `B.jpg`

   ```
   +-------------------+
   |                   |
   |       O.jpg       |
   |                   |
   +-------------------+
   ```

Notes:

- `A.jpg` and `B.jpg` must have equal height. If `B.jpg` is taller, it will be cut off. If `A.jpg` is taller, the right side of the image will have a blank strip of padding.
- `A.jpg` must have a width that ends on a complete block. (Usually means divisible by 8?)
- `B.jpg` may have any width, and does not have to be a multiple of the block size.

Comment: I think that JPEG files that use chroma subsampling need to be divisible by 16 not 8, although I could be wrong about that. And it's probably necessary for both files to have the same subsampling option or they won't combine properly.

Comment: PSA: `mozjpeg` provides `jpegtran` which supposedly supports the `-drop` flag, as it does not show any errors and the `man` page explains how to use it, but it does not actually do anything and for that you need to find another version

Answer (score 1):

The `jpegtran` man page and the two windows apps ([JpegCrop](http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/) and [JpegJoin](http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/jpegtran/)) are fairly good. If you have a specific procedure you are trying to accomplish, please update your question to explain it.

Myself, I have used `-drop` to do lossless spriting of JPEGs on my company home page:
http://bestelec.co.uk/images/front/features.jpg

1. First, I cropped the original photos down (on pixel boundaries) to encompass the frame required. This step can be saved losslessly using a non-JPEG format. [Art direction]
2. I next scaled these images down to the necessary width as required by the web design. Again, saved losslessly since these are intermediate steps.
3. Then I ran them through `cjpeg` with various quality options, until I found the lowest quality setting I was comfortable with.
4. (Optional) Next I cropped the bottom edge of each reduced quality individual image to align with the penultimate MCU boundary on the vertical axis. This allowed me to join the photos in a vertical strip with no gaps. My web design doesn't require a certain height so I was free to choose one here. If your component images' extents are not aligned on MCU boundaries (as my right edges were not), be sure you are using the October 2012 build of jpegtran/JpegJoin, otherwise only the first image will show up uncropped.
5. Lastly, I joined the images together into one jpeg, and ran the result through `jpegtran -optimise -progressive -copy none` to make it as small as possible, and progressive.

The net result is I have reduced three HTTP requests to one, allowing subsequent resources on the same host to be requested earlier and improving load times. This was a bigger win for me than converting the images to WebP and serving them individually, especially given that most of our corporate visitors are using IE.

Comment: why are you using sprites for .jpeg images? It is supposed that jpeg images are content, not background. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/compass-users/NCfZE2mkWJI

Comment: @tirengarfio these JPEGs are basically decoration, not content.

Comment: @Unsigned That's not a good reason to downvote this answer. The asker of the original question seemed to know how to use the `drop` option, I was not trying to write documentation for it, no matter how much you wanted to find that.

Comment: @Unsigned Can you post a question and link to it in these comments and I'll try to answer it for you. I don't know what exactly you're looking for. Have you been unable to use the `-drop` parameter, or are you getting somewhere but still have issues?